# Unable to do leg day

Tags: squats, legs

I started gym last month. I go to gym 5 days a week.I am happy with my workout in 4 days out of these (I can do more than 6 exercises given in my schedule ) but unfortunately on leg day I cant finish more than two exercises. Please help me here.

Below is the exercises schedule for leg day:

- Regular squat 4x12-15
- Hawk squats 3x10-12
- Leg press 4x12-15
- Leg extension 4x12-15
- Leg adduction & abduction 4x15-20
- standing calf press 3x20-30
- Seated calf press 3x10-12

Comment: Who made you that routine? What are your goals? Bodybuilding, strength, feeling sweaty after an intense workout? There are only two things worth doing on leg day unless you have very specific goals, squat and deadlift. If you are short on time, stick to what is efficient and that's not what that schedule is

Comment: @Raditz_35 - "*There are only two things worth doing on leg day unless you have very specific goals, squat and deadlift*" - I would contest this. Squats and deadlift are certainly the staples of any leg workout, but we're lacking side-to-side movement, as well as any athletic, power-based movement.

Comment: @Alec you need to be invested in fitness more than I think 95-99% of the population for having the time, mind and urge to train that efficiently, btw the OP is a beginner and hasn't included that really into their current routine. Being a complete athlete is a very specific goal imo. Let's not get carried away with things and demand perfection. Maybe we should all try to be perfect, but don't tell me the average person needs more than those 2 if time or some other resource is sparse.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason for training volume you use? I would ask you two questions:

1. are you world class pro (in your goal)?
2. do you take performance enhancing drugs (PEDs)?

If your answer is NO for both questions, then you are probably doing just a little bit much. What I would suggest:

Train twice per week for 30 minutes. Every second-week evaluate how you progress with your goals and adjust the volume:

- progress + no sore/pain: great! continue!
- no progress + no sore/pain: add a little bit more (more training or use longer training)
- progress or no progress + sore/pain: do less!

It is not that difficult. Do not be the guy "things working well, help me to screw it up!".

**Additional info:**
There are two main approaches to how to set volume.

1. find a minimal volume that delivers results
2. find a maximal volume that is possible to survive

Most people should go with the 1. approach. The exception is If you are genetic freak sport professional high on PEDs with ten years of full-time training experience. The reason are simple:

- The second approach is a direct way to get injured or at least tired
- The second approach does not necessarily deliver any progress (however it consume much more time)
- If you are a beginner (~6 months), you can do just the barest basics with the minimal volume and you will still gain great results.

**Note:** There is one more exception when to use the second approach: If you want to get wasted by training without reaching any goal, then go wild with the second approach. But be ready to sacrifice your health.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, movements like squats and deadlifts are much more taxing on the body than pretty much any upper body movement. In short, they utilise the whole body and they tax your central nervous system. Secondly, the first 4 exercises train the exact same muscles, Would you do 4 different variations of bench press followed by 4 different variations of tricep extension on push day? probably not.

If you're insistent on doing lots of variation (I'm not sure where you got this number 6  from) then you will have to lower the weight of all the exercises until you can get through them all. I'd suggest not going to failure on your 'regular squats' at all, always have 1-4 reps in reserve. Although after years of squatting Squat + 2 variations is more than enough volume for me.

This last bit is just my opinion. I would say there is no point in you doing leg adduction & abduction if you're doing regular squats. I'm also not a huge believer in calf raises so i would drop either seated or standing. doing both is a waste of time. (again it's my personal opinion that any calf raises are a waste of time for anyone not competing in bodybuilding).